# Equality as "makes" vs equality as "equals"

Tags: secondary-education, primary-education, equal-sign

A problem I often encounter while introducing students to equations is that of changing the conceptual image of the equation symbol $=$ from "results to" to "is equal to". To be more precise:

1. In the expression $2+3=5$, equality is often conceptualized by students as a predicate that denotes that the quantity on the LHS results to the quantity on the RHS. So, under this view, the reflexive property of equality as an equivalence relation is ignored.
2. In the expression $2x+4=5-3$, equality is/should be concpetualized as "the LHS is equal to the LHS and vice versa" - more or less in a sense similar to that of "balancing" on the two sides of a libra.

The first notion of equality is often and strongly interferring with the second one, something which could be realized e.g. due to students having dfficulties in recognizing $x=3$ and $3=x$ as equaly valid mathematical expressions of the same thing.

I do realize that this problem comes alongside with the introduction of mathematic notation that is structurally different from the way natural language is structured. Namely, a typical sentece has the form:
$$\text{Subject - Verb - Object}$$
where the object usually is the receiver of the subject's action(s) or their result(s). So, $x=3$ is naturally translated to "(The subject) $x$ equals (the object) $3$". However, it would seem odd to translate $3=x$ to "(The subject) $3$ equals (the object) $x$".

So, do you have any suggestions/activities that would help students nurture themselves to equality as an equivalence relation against maintaining the false image of equality as a "results" process?

Comment: Instead of having them try to decipher these equations, why not provide the context in plain English?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? In general, I never introduce equations as mere equations but through activities regarding the conceptualization of an "unknown" quantity and/or some problems. Yet, the misconception of equality is a persistent one even in students that do get the idea of an equation up to some decent degree.

Comment: I meant that one would tell the students either: "Simplify the expression 2+3" or: "Solve the equation 2x+4=5-3".

Comment: Or "Is it true that 1+4 = 2+3?"  That requires both simplifying (or evaluating) each side to examine whether they are equal to one another.  I agree with Peter on this.

Comment: In appropriate circs, I read $=$ as something like “results in” and see no problem with the students doing it, too. The problem is that the students the OP describes have ingrained in their minds that it is the only reading of $=$. This causes trouble in other contexts. Extending the meaning of a word to other ones in different contexts is a common cognitive problem. The OP seeks advice on how to do it for $=$. The previous comments do not seem to read the OP’s question in the same way.

Comment: @user1527 Thank you very much! You seem to have captured the quintessence of my question! I have encountered the same problem in other circumstances in mathematics education, but $=$ is by far the most troubling for me.

Comment: I'm just nitpicking here, but technically I am not so sure about the way you are identifying subject and object in those sentences. I am not a grammar expert (nor a mother-tongue English speaker), but I think that "equals" is a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) and thus "3" in your first example is a [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement), not an object.

Comment: The really awful thing is when they write stuff like $2+2=4\times2=8$. Here they're writing math as if it were the string of calculator keystrokes. I've tried pointing out to them that it's simply not true that $2+2=4\times2$, but this doesn't seem to sink in.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You may be correct, but this is not entirely relevant to the discussion at hand.  Perhaps this is a question for [linguistics.se]?

Comment: @XanderHenderson It is relevant in that it invalidates one of OP's arguments.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni In what way does it invalidate which argument?  And please note that both "to make" and "to equal" are, in the examples above, transitive verbs which *do* take direct objects ("to be" is different, but that applies only to the example in my answer, and is not relevant to the examples in the question above).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Subject/Object implies an asymmetry, which is a lot less pronounced with copulas. I am not so sure that "equals" in this construction can be considered a transitive verb, but you are right that it would make a good question for [linguistics.se] or [elu.se].

Comment: @FedericoPoloni But in the mind of the reader, this asymmetry *does exist*---that is the entire issue!  Whether or not this is a *correct* reading of the sentence "two plus three equals five" (and I would argue that it is not incorrect), it is how the sentence is understood:  five is acted upon via equality.  The question "What happened to five?" is answered by the sentence "Two plus three equals five," or "Five was equated to two plus three." (oh!  passive voice!  ack!)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni As Xander has pointed out, my main concern is not how we, the math isntructors, understand such questions/the $=$ symbol, but how the students conceptualize the notion of equality and the equality sign. So, it is the corresponding mental representation and mental schemata tham matter and not the actual linguistic background of the sentence. I just suggest that the typical linguistic structure of most languages (actually, SVO is a global grammatic schema) is not compliant with the structure of the corresponding "mathematical sentence".

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, I suspect that part of the problem is that the verbs "to make" and "to equal" are transitive verbs (they take a direct object).  Thus there is real distinction in the grammatical structure between the left-hand side and the right-hand side of an equation when read aloud.  To see the effect of this, consider what happens when you elide the direct object (the right-hand side of an equation):

> Two plus three makes.

Makes what?  What does two plus three make?  Where is the end of the sentence?  If you replace "makes" with "equals", you have the same problem—the sentence requires a direct object in order make sense.

Hence I would suggest using a entirely different grammatical structure.For example, use "is" as a synonym for "equals".  Note that the following is (in fact) a complete sentence:

> Two plus three is.

Here, "two plus three" is an object which exists, on its own.  The sentence makes sense without a direct object—indeed, the verb "to be" does not take a direct object at all.  The sentence simply declares that this thing, two plus three, exists.  The notation
$$ 2+3 = 5 $$
may be expanded to "two plus three **is** five", which provides additional information about the nature of two plus three.  Grammatically, the word "five" here is a predicate noun, which means that it falls into a somewhat distinct grammatical category from a direct object (the predicate noun is not being acted upon, but rather completes the verb phrase beginning with "is").  You can add verbosity for clarity:

> Two plus three is exactly the same as five.

Comment: Well, that was a nice view on the topic. Would you consider meaningful extending the former trick by also using expressions much like "five is two plus three", so as to highlight the symmetry included in the $=$ symbol?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Absolutely.  If two plus three is five, then five is two plus three.  They are one and the same.

Comment: See my comment to the question about the grammar here.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I fail to see how this is relevant to the discussion of mathematical pedagogy here, but I have added clarification.

Comment: Closely related: this question on math stackexchange, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738360/what-exactly-is-an-equation and my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738360/what-exactly-is-an-equation/2738382#2738382